# How do I create a simple boost::lambda function?

Tags: boost, boost-lambda

I'm trying to create a simple function that makes a simple test and return true or false.

```
myfunct = (_3 < someArray[i]);
```

When I do this, I get this error :

```
error: no match for 'operator<' in '<unnamed>::_1 < depths[i]'
```

What I hope is get something equivalent to this

```
bool myFunct(unsigned int a, unsigned int b, unsigned int c, unsigned int d)
{
   return c < 22; // Suppose 22 was in someArray[i]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you've got the namespaces right?

It should be either

```
using namespace boost::lambda;
```

or

```
boost::lambda::_1
```

Remember that placeholders are used in other parts of boost, or in other libraries (conflict with a local TR1 may happen!), which may induce errors.

Comment: Yes, I think it's my problem. I though about it on my way to work (after I posted this question), but could not test it because my code was at home. You just confirmed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following compiles without any errors, how does the rest of your code look like?

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::lambda;

int main(void)
{
    int someArray[5];
    int i;
    function<bool(int,int)> f = (_1 < someArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1: for actual code -- no access to a compiler right now so I couldn't provide that :/